# Ant Design Tabs remain unchanged when clicking to browser back button. How to change tabs when state updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSVGV.png)I am using Ant design tabs where i have linked different URL with each tabs . When i switch tabs by clicking its works perfectly but when i press back button so my URL also get update but tabs are not changing as per URL changes. I have to reload full page for changes. So is there any way to change tabs when my state or URL get updated.

here is my code

```
const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const setActiveTabValue = () => {
        let path = props.location.pathname;
        if (path.endsWith(`/dictionary`) || path.endsWith(`/dictionary/`)) {
            setActiveTab('Dictionary');
        } else if (path.endsWith(`/measures`) || path.endsWith(`/measures/`)) {
            setActiveTab('Measures');
        } else if (path.endsWith(`/fingerprints`) || path.endsWith(`/fingerprints/`)) {
            setActiveTab('Fingerprints');
        } else if (path.endsWith(`/lineage`) || path.endsWith(`/lineage/`)) {
            setActiveTab('Lineage');
        } else if (path.endsWith(`/impact`) || path.endsWith(`/impact/`)) {
            setActiveTab('Impact');
        } else if (path.endsWith(`/filter-policies`) || path.endsWith(`/filter-policies/`)) {
            setActiveTab('Filter Policy');
        } else if (path.endsWith(`/mask-policies`) || path.endsWith(`/mask-policies/`)) {
            setActiveTab('Mask Policy');
        } else if (path.endsWith(`/my-access`) || path.endsWith(`/my-access/`)) {
            setActiveTab('My Access');
        } else if (path.endsWith(`/quality`) || path.endsWith(`/quality/`)) {
            setActiveTab('Quality');
        } else if (path.endsWith(`/profile`) || path.endsWith(`/profile/`)) {
            setActiveTab('Profile');
        } else {
            setActiveTab('Dictionary');
        }
    }

function callback(key) {
  console.log(key);
}

// And here is the jsx part

   <Tabs defaultActiveKey={activeTab} onChange ={(activeKey) => onClickTab(activeKey)}  className={leftPanelState ?"ml-3 dataset-tabs": isDictionaryPath?`${dictionaryNavMargin}`:'ml-n4 dataset-tabs'} >
    <TabPane key={'Dictionary'} tab="Dictionary">
      Content of Tab Pane 1
    </TabPane>
   <TabPane key={'Measures'} tab={'Measures'}>
      Content of Tab Pane 2
    </TabPane>
     <TabPane key={'Fingerprints'} tab={'Fingerprints'}>
      Content of Tab Pane 3
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane key={'Lineage'} tab="Lineage">
      Content of Tab Pane 3
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane key={'Impact'} tab="Impact">
      Content of Tab Pane 3
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane key={'Profile'} tab="Profile">
      Content of Tab Pane 3
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane key={'Filter Policy'} tab="Filter Policy">
      Content of Tab Pane 3
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane key={'Mask Policy'} tab={'Mask Policy'}>
      Content of Tab Pane 3
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane key={'My Access'} tab={'My Access'}>V
      Content of Tab Pane 3
    </TabPane>
  </Tabs>
```

Please suggest me how i can change the tabs when my state gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your tab should have "key" set to your TabPane

Below is example

```
   <TabPane key={'Dictionary'} tab="Dictionary" key="Dictionary">
      Content of Tab Pane 1
    </TabPane>
```

Also,  should have "activeKey" too. It would be `activeKey={activeTab}`

If it still doesnt work, try removing "activeKey" from Tab

Source: https://ant.design/components/tabs/#Tabs

Comment: Thankyou for your solution.

I have used this but still the problem was not fixed.

Comment: @PradhyumnkumarSoni Hey, I updated my answer. Your tabs lacked "key", and "key" is what determines the activated tab.  

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ztvb9